# How can I use a while loop in java to find the sum of all numbers between 0 and a given integer?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'am happy to join the community. I have no prior experience to coding and I am currently experiencing my very first steps into java programming. Can someone please help me understand and solve the problem in the labs about the loop in java. Please find attached the screenshots of the labs.
Thank you for helping[[Loops in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZty2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FkEL.png)

What is the code for a while loop to get the sum of all numbers between 0 and end (exclusive)

Comment: please do not post images of code, as it is inconvenient for any volunteer who wants to help to manually type out everything

Comment: also, consider: 1) what are you doing to increment the sum? 2) if you return the sum inside the while loop, there will be no iteration as the method immediately exits

Comment: I suggest to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). after you do that, feel free to edit your post and we will try to help you

Comment: the solution is also actually written inside the notes/pre-reading for your lab, so try taking a look through

Comment: `(end * (1 + end)) / 2` -- Math

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that your *while-loop* is commented-out.

Here is a Java tutorial on *while* and *do-while* loops.
[The while and do-while Statements (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

In Java, to create a while-loop, you use the following structure.

```java
while (i < end) {

}
```

To derive a sum of values, from *i* to an exclusive *end*, you can use the following.

```java
sum = sum + i;
i = i + 1;
```

To return the *sum* value, you use

```java
return sum;
```

All together the code for the *whileExample* method would be as follows.

```java
int whileExample(int end) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < end) {
        sum = sum + i;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```